# Link tag not going into a Flexbox using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a nav bar with a div inside set as a flexbox. Inside of that I want a logo and a contact me button.

My problem is the link tag won't go into the flexbox.

I've tried putting the link tag inside of a div (which for some reason just had a size 0,0 div centered in the screen and didn't wrap the Link tag), I've tried getting rid of the div inside of the Nav and making the Nav the flexbox, I've tried getting rid of the Nav outside the div, I've tried a lot of stuff but came here because for some reason nothing is working for me.

Any help you can provide would be very greatly appreciated!

Navbar.js:

```
<nav className = "navBar">
   <div className="navbar-container">
       <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
           <img className = "navbar-picture" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/logo.jpeg'} alt="image" />
       </Link>
       <Button on buttonStyle = 'btn--outline'>Say Hello</Button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Navbar.css:

```
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-picture {
    width:100%;
}
```

In Browser:

[picture of the logo not in the flexbox it should be in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OinDc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting it like this

```
`.navbar-container .navbar-logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
}`
```

Comment: Hi Mudidi,
Thanks for the reply! My goal is to have the logo go inside of the div and use a flexbox for formatting. This gets rid of the flexbox. Do you have any ideas that could help me get the logo into the flexbox? Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your flex element with divs around it.

```html
<div className="navbar-container">
     <div>
     <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
               <img className = "navbar-picture" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/logo.jpeg'} alt="image" />
           </Link>
    </div>
<div className = "second-navbar-element">
<Link to="/" className="second-navbar-element-link">
               second-navbar-element
           </Link>
</div>
</div>
```